# Uploading upgrade version to Google Play

Tags: android, upgrade, publish

I am trying to upload v 1.1 of my application. 
I guess I don't have to define a new application but when I try to upload a new APK I get an error stating that v1 is already exist. 
I don't see how to change v1.0 to v1.1.
Can someone refer me to a proper documentation.

Thanks,
  Simon

Comment: Can you please paste your manifest.xml file so that we can check if you have made some mistake.

Comment: OK, this is basically the answer to my question. I have checked the manifest file, changed the version name and it works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To increase the version of your android app you need to change the versioncode and versionname in your mainfest.

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      package="com.example.package.name"
      android:versionCode="2" 
      android:versionName="1.1">
```

The versioncode can only be an integer, just increase it by one every time you upload a new version. The versionname can be a string, here you define the version displayed in the Google Play Store.

Additional information: 
http://developer.android.com/tools/publishing/versioning.html